# RecursiveDirectoryIterator indent subfolders

Tags: php, file, recursion, directory, indentation

I list all my files and folders using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, and I would like to display the result the same way an explorer would do.
For that I would need to indent the subfolders, but I have no idea how to do that...
I could use a subfolder counter, but it would only work for level 1, for level 2 it wouldn't work...

Here's my code :

```
    $nb=1;
    $read_folder = './cases/';
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($read_folder), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    $nb++;
    if ($file->isDir()) {
        $list_docs .= '<li class="docResult"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>&nbsp;<span id="file_'.$nb.'">'.$file->getFilename().'</span></li>';   
    } else {
        $list_docs .= '<li class="docResult"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>&nbsp;<span id="file_'.$nb.'">'.$file->getFilename().'</span></li>';   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - any issues feel free to ask - I will try and assist.

Comment: New version of the code is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is version 2 of the program to traverse a directory tree.

It has to be a different program because of the requirement to sort the output so that directories and printed before files.

Now, it seemed so simple when I started searching for answers. Hmm... ;-/

I eventually came to the conclusion that i would either have to use a ready made package such as [synfony : The Finder Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) or write my own `Directory iterator` component.

I have done the latter and made my own `SortedDirectory` class.

The output is not formatted in any way. It uses the default styling of the browser.

The source code for [class SortedDirectory](http://pastebin.com/w8d2zgpN) is available.

The code:

```
<?php // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470421/recursivedirectoryiterator-indent-subfolders

include 'Q31470421-sorted-directory-class.php';

$sourceFolder = 'P:\developer\xampp\htdocs\testmysql\Q23408272'; // top level directory to search
// $sourceFolder = 'P:\developer\xampp\htdocs\testmysql'; // top level directory to search

/**
 * Sorted Directory for the supplied path
 */
$dirIter = new SortedDirectory(new SplFileInfo($sourceFolder));

/**
 * Process the complete path recursing around as required..
 */
echo processDirectory($dirIter);

exit; // end the program

/**
 * Recurse around all the paths
 *
 * @param \SortedDirectory $directory
 */
function processDirectory(\SortedDirectory $directory, $depth = 0)
{
    $html = showOneDirectory($directory, $depth); // show all files in this directory

    foreach ($directory as $entry) {
        if ($entry->isDir()) { // recurse arount any sub-directories
            $html .= '<ul class="dir-start">';
            $html .=  processDirectory(new \SortedDirectory($entry), $depth + 1);
            $html .= '<!-- dir-end --></ul>';
        }
    }

    return $html;
}

/**
 * Process all the files for one directory
 *
 * @param \SortedDirectory $directory
 * @param type $depth
 * @return html
 */
function showOneDirectory(\SortedDirectory $directory, $depth = 0)
{
    $dirCount = 0;
    $fileCount = 0;
    $list_docs = '<ul>';
    foreach ($directory as $key => $entry) {


        if ($entry->isDir()) {
            $dirCount++;
            $list_docs .= '<li class="docResult">'
                          .'<i class="fa fa-folder">'
                          .'</i>&nbsp;<span id="file_'. $key .'">'
                          .' Directory: '
                          .' Name: '. $entry->getFilename()
                          .' | Path: '. $entry->getPath()
                          .' | Depth: '. $depth
                         .'</span></li>';
        }
        else {
            $fileCount++;
            $list_docs .= '<li class="docResult">'
                          .'<i class="fa fa-folder">'
                          .'</i>&nbsp;<span id="file_'. $key .'">'
                          .' File: '
                          .' Name: '. $entry->getFilename()
                          .' | Path: '. $entry->getPath()
                          .' | Depth: '. $depth
                         .'</span></li>';
        }
    }
    $list_docs .= '<li>'. "Counts: Dir: $dirCount, Files: $fileCount" .'</li>';
    return $list_docs .= '</ul>';
}
```

The `SortedDirectory` class:

If you want to change the sort order then edit:

`private function cmpEntry(SplFileInfo $entry1, SplFileInfo $entry2)`

```
<?php // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470421/recursivedirectoryiterator-indent-subfolders
      // Q31470421-sorted-directory-class

class SortedDirectory implements IteratorAggregate, Countable
{
    /**
     * Sorted directory list
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $directories = array();

    /**
     * sorted file list
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $files = array();

    private $allFiles = null;

    /**
     * Read the supplied directory into the two lists and sort them
     *
     * Ignore the '.' and '..' entries
     *
     * @param SplFileInfo
     */
    public function __construct(\SplFileInfo $directory)
    {
       foreach (new DirectoryIterator($directory->getRealPath()) as $entry) {
           if ($entry->isDir()) {
               $fname = $entry->getBasename();
               if (substr($fname, 0, 1) === '.') {
                   if ($fname === '.' || $fname === '..') {
                       continue;
                   }
                }
                $this->directories[] = clone $entry;
           }
           else {
               $this->files[] = clone $entry;
           }
       }
       $this->sortLists();
    }


    /**
     * Iterator of the sorted directory list
     *
     * @return \ArrayIterator
     */
    public function getDirIterator()
    {
       return new ArrayIterator($this->directories);
    }

    /**
     * Iterator of the sorted files
     *
     * @return \ArrayIterator
     */
    public function getFileIterator()
    {
       return new ArrayIterator($this->files);
    }

    /**
     * Iterator of all the directory entries
     *
     * @return \ArrayIterator All the files with directories before files
     */
    public function getIterator()
    {
       return new ArrayIterator($this->allFiles);
    }

    public function __get($property)
    {
       return $this->$property;
    }

    /*
     * Implement Iterator
     *
     */

    /**
     * @return \SplFileInfo
     */
    public function current()
    {
        return current($this->allFiles);
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function key()
    {
        return key($this->allFiles);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        return next($this->allFiles);
    }

    public function reset()
    {
        return reset($this->allFiles);
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        return reset($this->allFiles);
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return current($this->allFiles) !== false;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function count()
    {
        return count($this->allFiles);
    }

    /**
     * Sort lists using 'natural' compare
     */
    private function sortLists()
    {
       if (count($this->directories) >= 2) {
            usort($this->directories, array($this, 'cmpEntry'));
       }
       if (count($this->files) >= 2) {
            usort($this->files,  array($this, 'cmpEntry'));
       }

       $this->allFiles = array_merge($this->directories, $this->files);
    }

    private function cmpEntry(SplFileInfo $entry1, SplFileInfo $entry2)
    {
       return strnatcasecmp($entry1->getFilename(), $entry2->getFilename());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @ryan-vincent. Thanks a lot for the great answer. You even answer the next question I had, which was about displaying files under their current folder. You rock!

Comment: Oh one more little thing. When you declare SELF_FIRST, on depth 0 the containing folder is on top. But for other depth, the subfolders are always listed after the files, any idea how to correct that ? @ryan-vincent

Comment: @VincentTeyssier, Had a look at it ;-/. Sadly, It is not a 'little thing' ;-/. It is do-able. The first part is to provide a class that will allow, listing of the directories and files separately, in sorted order given a 'path', That is 'do-able' fairly cheaply.  Searched the web - lots of 'interesting' stuff. However, not sure how long it will take to sort out. ;-/ If you want to 'roll' your own then The symfony Finder component finds files and directories, via an intuitive fluent interface, that may be useful.

Comment: Actually I'm thinking of another way to do it. Instead of sorting the result, I will sort the <li> ids for each given depth. And then simply changing the <li> order by checking if directory or file... not sure if simpler, but at least that's something I'm able to do without help :)
Thanks a lot for the inestimable contribution.

Comment: @VincentTeyssier, if you want extra assistance feel free to post a comment. I would also be interested in how you finally solve it so we have another technique for solving this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

For records I've turned into a gist a class (`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`) that can read a directory with all its children and output a JSON or just an array.

https://gist.github.com/jonataswalker/3c0c6b26eabb2e36bc90

And a tree viewer of the output

http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/067c13